# Xulrunner and Gecko relationship

Tags: xulrunner, gecko

After read:

> Do not confuse the Gecko/XULRunner SDK
>   with XULRunner itself. The Gecko SDK
>   is a collection of header files and
>   tools used to develop general XPCOM
>   components which add functionality to
>   the existing platform, whereas
>   XULRunner is a framework which can be
>   used to run standalone or embedded
>   applications based on the Mozilla
>   framework.

I'm trying to understand: XULRunner uses Gecko? Or they have nothing to do with each other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gecko is the codename of Mozilla Corperation's rendering engine. It renders web pages. A browser however, needs to do more than just render HTML! It needs to: decode images, network HTTP transfer, etc... Is all done by OTHER components. Necko is one of those other components (for networking).

There is another product, XULRunner. Which embeds Gecko, Necko, and other libraries to form a complete 'product' which many of Mozilla products (including Firefox itself) are based off of.

This is firefox, in Mozilla terminology:

> - Gecko + Necko + libpr0n
>
>   - XULRunner
>
>     - Firefox (has it all)

Firefox is merely a *frontend* of **XULRunner**. And **Gecko** is the webpage renderer (a library) which **XULRunner** utilizes to display webpages.

Comment: Yes, that is what they called it. Should've been called `mozimg` or something like that, instead.